# ¿Como ordenar recursivamente un arreglo en python?

Tags: python, lista, recursión, ordenar

Implemente un codigo para organizar una lista de numeros de descendente a ascendente recursivamente, sin embargo, a la hora de ejecutar, me organiza la lista no de la manera esperada.

```
persona=[80,59,60,81,57,58,76,75]

variable=0
mayor=0

def equilibra(personas,x):
    global mayor
    longitud=len(personas)
    if x==longitud:
        return personas
    elif mayor<=personas[x]:
        mayor=personas[x]
        variable=personas[x]
        personas[x]=personas[longitud-1]
        personas[longitud-1]=variable
        return equilibra(persona,x+1)
    
    else:
        return equilibra(persona,x+1)

print(equilibra(persona,0))
```

Comment: la idea es con el metodo, ordenar la lista recursivamente de menor a mayor

Answer (score 0):

Con el algoritmo que propones solo estás moviendo el elemento mayor al final de la lista, pero todos los demás elementos quedan desordenados.

Para ordenar la lista de manera correcta usando el algoritmo de la burbuja como estás utilizando implícitamente debes:

1. Hacer que tu función mueva el elemento mayor al final de la lista. De esta manera ya queda asegurado que el mayor elemento de la lista está ordenado.
2. Como el mayor elemento de la lista está ordenado, llamas nuevamente a la función, pero esta vez haciendo que itere desde `1` hasta `n - 1`, donde `n` es la longitud de la lista. Es decir vamos ha iterar ahora en una sublista para mover el elemento mayor de esa sublista al final... y así sucesivamente.

Una posible implementación, que modifica la lista original sería:

```
def ordenar_burbuja(lista: list, n=None):
    if n is None:
        n = len(lista)

    # Caso Base
    if n == 1:
        return lista

    # Movemos el mayor elemento al final de la lista
    for i in range(n - 1):
        if lista[i] > lista[i + 1]:
            lista[i], lista[i + 1] = lista[i + 1], lista[i]

    # Ya el elemento mayor está al final, ahora volvemos a llamar a la función pero con
    # una sublista, es decir, sin incluir el último elemento ordenado
    return ordenar_burbuja(lista, n - 1)


persona = [80, 59, 60, 81, 57, 58, 76, 75]
ordenar_burbuja(persona)
print(persona) # Salida: [57, 58, 59, 60, 75, 76, 80, 81]
```

Si no quieres que modifique la lista original, simplemente has una copia de la lista al inicio de la función.

Una forma equivalente del algoritmo de la burbuja pero sin utilizar ciclos se puede implementar como:

```
import sys
MIN_INT = -sys.maxsize - 1  # Valor mínimo que puede tomar un entero

def sort(lista, indice=0, mayorValor=MIN_INT):
    if len(lista) == indice:
        return lista
    elif mayorValor > lista[indice]:
        lista[indice - 1] = lista[indice]
        lista[indice] = mayorValor
        mayorValor = lista[0]
        indice = 0
    else:
        mayorValor = lista[indice]

    return sort(lista, (indice + 1), mayorValor)


persona = [80, 59, 60, 81, 57, 58, 76, 75]
sort(persona)
print(persona)
```

Comment: no puedo usar ciclos :(, necesito hacerlo recursivamente. De antemano, muchas gracias con la ayuda, me puedo basar de eso para hacerlo de manera recursiva.

Comment: Te agregué una versión del mismo algoritmo pero sin usar ciclos. Es justo el mismo lo que se hace más difícil de leer.